# Laravel Sum value and group by

Tags: php, laravel

I have some issue, im using Laravel with DB table, i need to sum values, also display name (text field) and group by content id, the problem im getting, is that i get an mysql error saying, name is not on group by, well if i add name on group by it wont groupby content id and it will show repeat values...this is what i have:

```
DB::table('mytable')    
            ->addselect(DB::Raw('sum(items) as items'))
            ->addselect(DB::Raw('name as name'))
            ->addselect(DB::Raw('id as id')) 
            ->groupBy('id')
            ->get();
```

I need to display the name and items with sum, grouped by id.

Doing example above im getting mysql error asking to add name on groupby...witch gives me repeats values.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark for you `->addselect(DB::Raw('sum(items) as items, name, id'))->groupBy('id')`

Comment: I have experienced this before, it occurs when mysql is set to strict. Please change this `'strict' => true` to false in ***config/database.php***,

Comment: i cannot change that, need to solve it via query. This is a Laravel issue, since when i run the query on mysql works ok...i cannot change the value of strict...

Comment: Can you try by adding `DB_CONNECTION=mysql` in your .env file? Also, change your select as mentioned in admcfajn's comment